# What is this : ^[3;J^[H^[2J?

Tags: linux, debian, grep, netstat, watch

I am on a Debian system fresh installed, logged in via ssh on /dev/pts/0, and have entered the following command

```
watch -n 10 clear > /dev/pts/0 ; netstat -tupn 2>/dev/null | grep -v 3306 > /dev/pts/0
```

and what I get looks like this

```
Every 10.0s: clear                                              Thu Jan 30 17:42:01 2020

^[3;J^[H^[2J
```

Why is this linux box hating me ???

Comment: Since watch already refreshes the display, why are you explicitly telling it to clear the screen? Actually, you are watching the `clear` command - not very interesting...

Comment: @doreal no, I have there 2 things that I do each time: a clear and a netstat.

Comment: Why do you need to do a `clear`? Wouldn't `watch 'netstat -tupn | grep -v 3306'` work?

Comment: @doneal24  I thought that if I always finish the process, it eats less resources.

Comment: So you want to watch the output of `clear` every 10 seconds until you hit `^C`. After you're done with watching clear, you want to run `netstat` once. And all of this is output to a specific pseudo-terminal.

Comment: @doneal24 I can do clear > /dev/pts/0 and I do not get that funny string, and if I do that command on another box with a more older Debian I do not get that funny string also. And btw what does it represent ?

Comment: It is the "clear screen" escape sequence for ANSI terminals.However, sinnce `watch` is capturing input, it grabs the escape sequence and displays it. It also sends its own `clear screen` escape sequence to the output terminal independently of the command given.

Comment: @doneal24 I think you are right sending netstat to /dev/null each time does not save anything. but I still want to understand why my command is working on one box and it is not working on the other.

Comment: Running `clear > /dev/pts/0` should not give you that "funny screen" on any Linux system, although the results may not be want you expect if your terminal is not `/dev/pts/0`. `watch clear > /dev/pts/0` is an entirely different command and you should not expect the output to be the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It is the output of the `clear` command …

You ran `clear`.  `clear` produced these control sequences.  (They are merely in a different order on my machine.)

```
% clear | cat -v ; echo
^[[2J^[[H^[[3J
%
```

On an ECMA-48 terminal or terminal emulator these control sequences erase the display and position the cursor.

```
% clear | console-decode-ecma48
ED 2
CUP 0
ED 3
%
```

But the `watch` command interprets the standard outputs of the processes that it runs, and does not understand any ECMA-48 control sequences apart from one.  It only understands some of the TTY-37 control characters from 1968 and (if the `-c` flag is used) the SGR control sequence from ECMA-48.

Everything else it passes to ncurses, which prints control characters in caret notation.  But *because of a bug in `watch`*, the second character of a caret notation string is then immediately overwritten, and what should have been `^[[` comes out as `^[` in `watch`'s output.

## … and only the `clear` command.

The shell script is not quoted at all:

```
watch -n 10 clear > /dev/pts/0 ; netstat -tupn 2>/dev/null | grep -v 3306 > /dev/pts/0
```

So this is two pipelines, sequentially:

```
watch -n 10 clear > /dev/pts/0
netstat -tupn 2>/dev/null | grep -v 3306 > /dev/pts/0
```

The redirection happens before the commands are run, and in two cases is redirecting standard output to the pseudo-terminal that it was open to *anyway*.  They are effectively no-ops:

```
watch -n 10 clear 
netstat -tupn 2>/dev/null | grep -v 3306
```

## Your machine is doing exactly what you told it to do.

So you are watching the output of just the `clear` command, repeatedly, whose output isn't being processed as control sequences but simply printed in broken caret notation.

Exit `watch` to run your `netstat` command once.  ☺