# The deciphering of ncurses escape sequences

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, ncurses

Help me to decipher the escape sequences created by `ncurses` library and catched by `strace`. I am exploring how `ncurses` interacts with terminal and want to understand its "handshake protocol". I have found some descriptions already, but didn't understand all of them though, like "Set cursor key to cursor".

`echo $TERM` prints `xterm-256color`.

**Original**

```
write(1, "\33[?1049h\33[22;0;0t\33[1;39r\33(B\33[m\33[4l\33[?7h\33[H\33[2J", 46) = 46
write(1, "Hello World !!!", 15)   = 15  
write(1, "\33[39;1H\33[?1049l\33[23;0;0t\r\33[?1l\33>", 32) = 32
```

**My assumptions**

```
write(1, "
    \33[?1049h       # go to alternate screen
    \33[22;0;0t
    \33[1;39r
    \33(B            # Set United States G0 character set 
    \33[m            # Turn off character attributes
    \33[4l
    \33[?7h          # Set auto-wrap mode
    \33[H            # Move cursor to upper left corner
    \33[2J           # Clear entire screen
", 46) = 46

write(1, "Hello World !!!", 15)   = 15

write(1, "
    \33[39;1H
    \33[?1049l       # Go back to the initial screen
    \33[23;0;0t\r
    \33[?1l          # Set cursor key to cursor 
    \33>
", 32) = 32
```

**The testing program source**

```
int main()
{   
    napms(25000);               /* This pause is needed to catch the process by strace*/
    initscr();                  /* Start curses mode          */
    printw("Hello World !!!");  /* Print Hello World          */
    refresh();                  /* Print it on to the real screen */
    endwin();                   /* End curses mode        */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With open source libraries such as ncurses it's often easier to read the code than trying to reverse engineer it by looking at its effects. That said, I did not actually look at the code, it might just as well be a complete mess :-)

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I have tried this already, reading the source and debugging by `gdb` did not help :).

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324306/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289849/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/564981/5132 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For XTerm and anything that claims compatibility with it, you'll want this:

https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

You'll also need the manual for the VT100 terminal, which XTerm emulates and expands on:

https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/contents.html

The Linux `console_codes(4)` man page describes the control codes used by the Linux console, which is also a superset of VT100 and the man page sometimes has more verbose descriptions than the other sources above:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

The unknown codes in your example:

```
\33[22;0;0t
```

Here, the first part `\33[` (or `ESC [` ) is known as `CSI` or *Control Sequence Introducer*.

The `CSI <number> ; <number> ; <number> t` is a window manipulation sequence.
Control sequences ending with `t` always take three numeric parameters, but won't always use all of them. The first parameter is `22`, and the second is `0`, so this code tells the terminal emulator to save the current window and icon titles so that they can be restored later.

```
\33[1;39r
```

This is `CSI <number> ; <number> r`. The meaning is "set scrolling region". Setting this to something smaller than the size of the current window would efficiently allow keeping something static like a menu line at the top of a TUI display, a status line at the bottom, or both while displaying a lot of text within the scrolling region.

```
\33[4l
```

This is `CSI <one or more numbers> l`. The meaning is "reset mode". Value 4 resets (disables) "insertion-replace mode", or in plain terms, tells that anything printed to the screen should simply overwrite what was there before.

```
\33[39;1H
```

This is `CSI <number> ; <number> H`. This moves the cursor to the 39th line, 1st column.

```
\33[23;0;0t
```

This is another window manipulation sequence. This restores the previously-saved window and icon titles. Obviously your test program did not change the titles at all, but these sequences are part of the standard initialization/exit procedures done by `initscr()` and `endwin()` respectively.

```
\33[?1l          # Set cursor key to cursor
```

This sets the cursor keys of the VT100 keypad to the regular "cursor key mode". There was also another mode, intended to allow these keys to be used for application-specific purposes, like an extra set of function keys. The VT100 terminal produced different output for these keys according to the mode settings; this just ensures that if the application switched the cursor keys to a non-default mode, they will be returned to default mode before the program exits.

```
\33>
```

This is just `ESC >`. This is similar to the previous code, but for the numeric keypad.

Comment: "vt100" is too often, as here, bandied about for things that are *not VT 100s*.  The XTerm FAQ goes into some detail on this error. The Linux KVTs *are not* supersets of VT 100s, or even exactly compatible with DEC VTs.  They are very limited terminal emulators, with some well-known significant differences from DEC VTs.  Ironically, the SCO Console is a much clearer relation.  Other errors: CSI `t`does not always take 3 parameters.  The 3 parameter form is _a DTTerm extension_.  VT100s didn't have function keys. And really terminfo is the way to understand ncurses.